# Advanced search in Mediawiki

Tags: date, search, mediawiki

How do I find the article on the date or size?

```
For example, from 24/04/2013 to 04/01/2013 and the size of 12800 bytes
```

Is there such extensions in Mediawiki?

Comment: What date? Creation date, latest revision date?

Comment: latest revision date.
I saw an extension for mediawiki with more than 20 search criteria. But now I can not remember where I saw.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an extension, but you can use the [`allpages` API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aAllpages) to find pages by size and then [nest the query](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Generators) with a [retrieval of the revision timestamps](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv) by whom you can filter the result.